# What is a good concept to implement activity indicator

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uicollectionview, uiactivityindicatorview

In our iPgone & iPad app we use push segue transitions between different ui contollers, most of them extend `UICollectionViewController`. In each controller we load data from our internal API. Loading is done `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad`.
Now, the thing is, that this API call sometime can take a second or two, or even three... well, lot's of stuff there, let's assume we can't change it. But, we can change the user experience and at least add the "loading" circle indicator. The thing is, what I can't understand by means of correct concept, while transition from A to B, the "load" is done at B, while page A still presented.
So, question is "how do I show indicator on page A, while loading controller for page B?"
Thanks all,
Uri.

Comment: Well, you can simply do the API call in `viewDidLoad`, and call `loadView` on the view controller you want to present on a background thread, only pushing the segue after the download is complete. Are you having a problem with this approach?

Comment: @David I think it's not a big difference. If I push a button that starts a segue and nothing happens I will think something goes wrong

Comment: @user2759361 Obviously, the OP should show the activity indicator while loading the data in the background ;)

Comment: @David - not sure I understand how to implement this. Instantiate controller B from A? But how to tell the `performSegue` that the controller B is ready?

Comment: @urir What networking API are you using to load the data? In case of AFNetworking, you can pass a block that will be executed when the download finishes. You can use this block to tell the `A` that `B` finished loading. Something similar can be achieved via the delegate protocol in `NSURLConnection`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common approach in this case is to load data in destination view controller NOT in main thread. You can show indicator while loading data in background thread and then remove it.

Here is sample of code from my project solving the same problem:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    ...
    // add indicator
    self.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    self.spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    self.spinner.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:self.spinner];

    ...    
    // fetch news
    [self.spinner startAnimating];
     __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self
    [[BitrixApiClient sharedInstance] getLatestNewsWithCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *newsArray, NSUInteger maxPageCount, NSUInteger currentPageNumber, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            weakSelf.newsArray = newsArray;
            weakSelf.currentPageNumber = currentPageNumber;

            [weakSelf.newsTableView reloadData];
        }
        // stop spinning
        [weakSelf.spinner stopAnimating];
    }];
}
```

Comment: I am loading the data in each controller separately. Could you please explain how to "show indicator background thread"? You mean to show the indicator at view A? but how do I "clean" it after leaving to B?

Comment: I see the updated example, I think I understand, let me try it!

Comment: I"d like to mention, that it wolud be usefull to use weak pointer to self in blocks. Because user can go back from current viewController.   Before `[BitrixApiClient sharedInstance]` it would be usefull to create `__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self`   and thein in body of completion block `[weakSelf.newsArray = ...;, [weakSelf.spinner stopAnimating];  `